# Jenkins remove project via API via curl

Tags: php, curl, jenkins, jenkins-api

Good Morning,

We have an application which is in charge of handeling deployment, before sending the project in mockup, we are using jenkins to run some test.

On jenkins, we can create the project and run build without any problem using curl. But when we delete a project on our application we want to remove the project in Jenkins using the API.

Unfortunately, I can't seems to be able to find out how to remove a project using the API.

Does anyone know of a way to remove a project using the web API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to your job, `http://<MY_SERVER>/job/<MY_JOB>`, and find the link at the bottom that says "REST API" (this will take you to a url like `http://<MY_SERVER>/job/<MY_JOB>/api`. For me that page contains a header "Delete a job" under which it documents that to delete a job I need to send a POST request to `http://<MY_SERVER>/job/<MY_JOB>/doDelete`.

I hope this helps.

Reference: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Deleting-a-job-through-the-Remote-API-td3622851.html